# Random image load

Tags: javascript, html, image

so I already have a image randomiser, but i am now looking to extend this so that IF image 1 was loaded last, load image 2 and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var images = ['imageTest.jpg', 'imageTest2.jpg', 'imageTest3.jpg', 'imageTest4.jpg'];
    $('.mainHero-fluid').css({
    'background-image': 'url(/assets/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() *  images.length)] + ')',
    });

});
```

how can I do this?

Comment: if after 1 you are looking for 2, then thats not called random

Comment: simply remove the image from the array after using it so that you wont use it again

Comment: There a point missing here: do you want to randomize the image the next time the user refresh / access to the page? Or when? In the first case, you need to store the information somewhere. Like in a cookie or in a localStorage / sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I guess somthing like that should do it. You can gain the current Image from the source attribute of the image…

```
//copy the whole list
var newImages = [].concat(images), newImage;

//remove the current image
newImages.splice(images.indexOf(<currentImage>),1);

//get a random entry
newImage = newImages[Math.round(Math.random() * (newImages.length - 1))];
```

Good luck!